# Debug hook for table creation in Lua

Tags: lua

Is there a way to set a debug hook in Lua for whenever a table is created? I have a fairly complex program and want to see where all the tables are being created so I can optimize and reuse them if possible. Alternatively, is there a way to do this with a metamethod on tables?

Answer (score 1):

There is no debug hook for that.

You can do a static analysis of your code by searching the output of `luac -l` for `NEWTABLE`.

Comment: This is an embedded system with Lua being compiled in. Can I modify the luaH_new() in ltable to add a new hook? It is just hard to do the static analysis on the size of our program.

Comment: @Moop, sure you can change the code of Lua. If you manage to implement something nice, please share in the Lua mailing list. Thanks.

Comment: Are hooks supposed to only act on Lua-defined actions, or do they include the C layer?